# Locating tag by its text using css

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors

How would you get the following tag **using CSS**?

```
<p>You can only use the text inside the tag</p>
```

As in xpath I'd use the following:

```
//p[contains(text(), "inside the tag")
```

PS: I can't close the xpath, it tries to auto complete with code... :S

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with pure CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I was looking for!

```
p:contains("inside the tag")
```

Comment: @mateusza: As of today, none of them do. `:contains()` was dropped from the CSS3 spec and we haven't seen it return in the CSS4 drafts. jQuery and Selenium *do* implement it, though. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4781167/106224). Since the OP said he's using Selenium, this will work. It just won't work in a stylesheet.

Answer (score 4):

I believe CSS3 selectors can only filter *attributes*, not the text within tags. So you could do something like `a[href~="aspx"]` to match links to aspx pages, but that's as far as content-based matching can go.

For what you want to do, you'll probably have to use javascript or server-side processing.

Have a look at [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) and [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) for more information.

Comment: I'm almost sure that css selector exists. 
Thanks for the recommendations but I'd like to use the CSS selector as a Selenium locator, so only pure CSS can be used...