# Why doesn't the selector h3:nth-child(1):contains('a') work?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I check this selector:

```
h3:nth-child(1):contains('a')
```

selector doesn't work?

I check this in firefinder and does return nothing (not info that there is zero elements)

Then check this:

```
h3:nth-child(1)
```

and it returns h3, so selector is almost good, but something with this(h3 has text 'a') text goes wrong.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`:contains()` <del>is not</del> was going to be a CSS3 selector ([thanks T.J. Crowder for the link](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#content-selectors)), but it didn't make it, most likely because the way it works tends to lead to severe performance and over-selection issues. For example, if an element `E` matches `:contains()` for a given string argument, then *all of its ancestors* would also match; using it with a universal selector would lead to unexpected results with certain style properties, on top of being slow for the browser.

There is no other CSS selector that serves a purpose like `:contains()`. So you'll have to find some other way, either by modifying your HTML or even by using jQuery's `:contains()`, to achieve the effect you want:

> Select an `h3` element
>   if it is the first child of its parent
>   and its text contains the letter 'a'.

**For jQuery and Selenium RC users:** `:contains()` is implemented in the Sizzle selector engine used by jQuery, which is also used in Selenium RC (but *not* Selenium WebDriver). It works as described [in this decade-old revision of the CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors), but again, due to how the spec describes it, you need to use it with care or it may lead to unexpected selections.

On a final note, `h3:nth-child(1)` can be replaced with `h3:first-child`, which as a CSS2 selector has better browser support.

Comment: Indeed. It was going to be defined (there's even a section in the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/) for it, Section 6.6.6), but it wasn't.

Comment: `This section intentionally left blank. (This section previously defined a :contains() pseudo-class.)` Does that mean that the W3C took `:contains` out of the CSS3 spec? http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to use `:contains(a)` to find an anchor tag (rather than the letter *A*), you could use:

```
h3:nth-child(1) a
```

or

```
h3:first-child a
```

Comment: In this case he seems to want to target the first descendant of `h3`, only if they have an `a` inside. Your selector would target the `a` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> The `:contains()` pseudo-class isn't in the CSS Spec and is not supported by either Firefox or Chrome.

You can find a couple of detailed discussion in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException with "span:contains('string')"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidselectorexception-with-spancontainsstring/47884814#47884814)
- [Finding link using text in CSS Selector is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53351028/finding-link-using-text-in-css-selector-is-not-working/53355811#53355811)

---

### Solution

As a solution you have to drop the `contains()` part and your effective locator will be:

```
h3:nth-child(1)
```

Further as @BoltClock mentioned within his answer, you can also use:

```
h3:first-child
```

As an alternative, you can also use:

```
h3:first-of-type
```

---

### tl; dr

- [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException with "span:contains('string')"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidselectorexception-with-spancontainsstring/47884814#47884814)
- [Finding link using text in CSS Selector is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53351028/finding-link-using-text-in-css-selector-is-not-working/53355811#53355811)