# CSS Spec Implementation

Tags: css, css-selectors

I just had a case where it would have been really useful if there were a CSS selector like `:numeral`. I could then make all the numerals superscript and change their color.

It then occurred to me that it would be even more useful to have something like `:regex('...')` which would allow me to use regex to select particular text (numerals preceded by a space, for example: `:regex(' \\d*')`).

Is there a good reason this sort of selection should not be implemented in CSS Spec?

Comment: @Steeven: Re your suggested edit, "if there were" is the correct construction (it's the "subjunctive" or "speculative" tense).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a good reason this sort of
>   selection should not be implemented in
>   CSS Spec?

Yes - performance reasons.

A common request is a "parent selector" (similar to jQuery's [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)), which is also rejected for similar performance reasons.

A good read on this subject is: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors

The sheer length of that article is why I'm not attempting to explain this myself.

If a parent selector is too bad from a performance viewpoint, you can imagine that a "regex selector" would be unthinkable.

Especially when you consider that not all regexes are equal: it's very easy to make *very slow* regexes.

For example: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: Trying to find sources citing the reason why the `:contains()` pseudo-class was dropped, but to no avail.

Comment: @BoltClock: 6.6.6 eh? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781141/why-h3nth-child1containsa-selector-doesnt-work/4781167#4781167

Comment: Parent selectors and a `:regex` selector are fundamentally different, I wouldn't generalize from performance aspects of the one to comment on performance aspects of the other.

Comment: This is true, partially. I disagree in that the scope of supported regex could be reduced to avoid "catastrophes" (although having said that, I question it to some degree). Nevertheless, the problem with parent (ancestor) selectors - with which I am familiar - is that later dom affects earlier rendering. This is not the case with regex because it has to *match* an expression.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I agree that my reasoning is faulty. I just went with what I could think of :( I am at least correct with the "performance" idea in my answer, see the red text in an [older revision of the CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-selectors-20001005/#content-selectors). If `:contains` has "performance issues", then `:regex` would be much, much worse.

Comment: @j3frea: You might want to post your question here: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/. You'll get a better answer than I can provide.

Comment: I think the performance issues are because of matches like `M</STRONG><EM>arkup` on `:contains("Markup")`. Regex may well have worse possibilities though.

Comment: @thirtydot: Yes, if `:contains` has performance issues, `:regex` should have at least the same issues. (I doubt they'd be "much, much worse" though; regex engines in browsers are pretty quick.) Though there's the question of whether performance is the problem of the specification (this isn't directed at you, but rather at the W3C); I tend to prefer caveat user (let the user beware). There are lots of things we can do that can have performance impacts...