# text selectors in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am wondering if there are any other selectors which select only *part* of an HTML element. I know of these two:

```
:first-letter
:first-line
```

But AFAIK there are no other selectors which do this. I am interested in any (even browser-specific) selectors or other methods of manipulating only part of a block of text.

**The Use Case**

I have (more) control over the .css and .js than over the DOM. I've been using js workarounds but want to include any CSS solutions as well, because I don't like to depend of javascript for my styles.

Even if the solution is only supported in konquerer it is still better than nothing IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, those are the only two [content pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements) available that select real text nodes. Nothing new has made it into the CSS3 recommendation.

One of the proposals that didn't make it was [`::selection`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-selection) (roughly implemented by Opera, Safari and Chrome, and by Firefox as `::moz-selection`), but your use case doesn't really say anything about what you want to do so I have no idea if that selector is relevant to your needs.

Comment: eh, I was hoping for something like `:nth-letter` or `:nth-line`. I know it was a long shot but really, why include those two if you won't take it to the logical conclusion?

Comment: oh, and while i'm compiling a wish list a `:contains(text)` selector would be cool too :)

Comment: @JIStone: Performance constraints, really. The first letter/line is pretty easy to calculate but anything beyond that makes things very complicated for rendering. Also, there *was* a `:contains()` pseudo-class as well, but it doesn't select the text, it selects the *element* that contains it. Like `::selection`, [it was dropped from the spec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781141/why-h3nth-child1containsa-selector-doesnt-work/4781167#4781167), but unlike it, no browser supports it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any browser-specific pseudo-elements, but there are also the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.  See the [CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cover.html#minitoc) from the W3C.