# How to extract tags with content that have certain substring using CSS selectors?

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors, substring, webdriver

I have the following HTML:

```html
<tr bgcolor="#DEDEDE">
    <td>
        <b>OK:Have idea</b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <b>KO:Write code</b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <b>KO:Run code</b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <b>KO:Debug code</b>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to extract the following:

```html
<b>KO:Write code</b>
<b>KO:Run code</b>
<b>KO:Debug code</b>
```

By the substring `KO:`. How do I do it using CSS selector expressions?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with CSS

Comment: What do you mean you want to **extract** them? CSS is used for styling elements - I'm not sure what you're aiming to do with it. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I'd like use WebDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector(cssSelectorString));
function to select the WebElements that are relevant;
I need the css selector string to do the above job..

Comment: Is there an XPath version of the `cssSelector` method?

Comment: @mu is too short: If he's using Selenium, yes there is. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:contains()` which was [dropped from the CSS3 spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781141/why-h3nth-child1containsa-selector-doesnt-work/4781167#4781167) but is implemented by Selenium:

```java
WebDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td b:contains('KO:')"));
```

There is no equivalent pseudo-class for starts-with or ends-with, though, so `:contains()` is the furthest you can go with a CSS locator. If you need to filter only by starting with the substring `KO:`, you should use an XPath locator:

```java
WebDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//td/b[starts-with(text(), 'KO:')]"));
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but got this error..:

Sep 27, 2011 6:55:32 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomNode querySelectorAll
SEVERE: Error parsing CSS selectors from 'td b:contains('KO:')': Error in pseudo class or element. Invalid token "KO:". Was expecting one of: <S>, ")", <IDENT>.
com.steadystate.css.sac.TestCSSParseException: Error in pseudo class or element. Invalid token "KO:". Was expecting one of: <S>, ")", <IDENT>.

It seems that if I strip out the quotes from KO: it runs but returns a 0 size result. currently i'm using selenium 2.6.0.

Comment: The xpath expression didn't work, it seems that it returns b even if the substring wasn't KO..

Comment: What if you used `"td b:contains(\"KO:\")"` instead for CSS? Not so sure about XPath...