# CSS selector inside XPath

Tags: css, xpath, css-selectors

Is it possible to specify a CSS selector inside an XPath? Essentially, I want to find elements that satisfy both `.myClass div` and `div[contains(., 'Hello!')]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't combine CSS selector syntax and XPath syntax into a single expression. Neither language has any feature that lets you feed an expression from the other.

You can only incorporate the CSS selector into the XPath *as XPath*, which means you'll need to translate it yourself. In your case, here's the resultant XPath expression:

```
//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' myClass ')]//div[contains(., 'Hello!')]
```

Of course, this depends on what you can accomplish with CSS selectors or XPath. For example, [if the `:contains()` pseudo-class hadn't been dropped from CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4781167/106224), you would have been able to use this CSS selector just as well:

```
.myClass div:contains('Hello!')
```

But it's been removed from the spec, so you'll only be able to get it to work as a jQuery selector or a Selenium CSS locator.

Comment: `contains(@class, 'myClass')` also matches `AmyClassman`. It's better to use something like `contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' myClass ')`

Comment: @lwburk: I was hoping for a solution around that. Thanks! I've updated my answer.