# Forming XPATH Selector in SCRAPY

Tags: python, css, scrapy

Trying to pull the product name from a page:

https://www.v12outdoor.com/view-by-category/rock-climbing-gear/rock-climbing-shoes/mens.html

Can't find XPATH which returns useful, specific result.

Apologies for my first post being such a beginner question :(

```
class V12Spider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'v12'
start_urls = ['https://www.v12outdoor.com/view-by-category/rock-climbing-gear/rock-climbing-shoes/mens.html']


def parse(self, response):
    yield {
        'price' : response.xpath('//span[@id="product-price-26901"]/text()'),
        'name' : response.xpath('//h3[@class="product-name"]/a/text()'),
           }
```

for `name`, I expected to produce the name from items in `h3` tags with class class `product-name` but generates multiple rows of data='\r\n

(whilst we're at it for `price`, is there any way to only pull the numerical values out?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing can be solved using get() method for xpath and then using strip() method for string.
I tried something like this

```py
name= response.xpath('//h3[@class="product-name"]/a/text()').get()
```

Gives

```py
'\r\n                                RED CHILLI VOLTAGE                            '
```

Then using

```py
name.strip()
```

gives

```py
'RED CHILLI VOLTAGE'
```

So you can replace your name statement with

```py
name= response.xpath('//h3[@class="product-name"]/a/text()').get().strip()
```

**Same solution to get price just add .get().strip at the end of your statement**

Hopefully this helps.
Also read about .getall() method from https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

Comment: Thank you so much for that - was getting confused no end, despite knowing it was simple!

Comment: The xpath/css selectors are used to get the elements and we call .get() or .getall() or extract_first() to get the data inside (read difference in documentation). It's just a common mistake many people forgetfully do ;)

Comment: On to the next dumb question ...

def parse(self, response):
        for shoe in response.css('.item'):
            yield {
                    'name' : shoe.xpath('//h3[@class="product-name"]/a/text()').().strip(),
                    'price' : shoe.xpath('//p[@class="special-price"]/span[@id="product-price-26901"]/text()').get().strip(),
                }

I was expecting it to return data for the 12 items on the page, instead get 12 x 1st entry ... What am I missing about the reiteration?! Sorry again for being so rubbish and missing the obvious!

Comment: Or can I use strip() with getall() ? It seems to all be going wrong!

Comment: I think this is because you are combining css and xpath selectors as answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005170/css-selector-inside-xpath though *I might be wrong* since I am not proficient in using xpaths

Comment: But the fix to your problem using only css selectors is. . . . .                                             
```
def parse(self, response):
    for shoe in response.css('.item'):
        yield {'name': shoe.css('.product-name a::text').get().strip(),
               'price': shoe.css('.special-price .price::text').get().strip()
               }```

Comment: Thank you so much for all your assistance, really ver appreciated.