# How do I test CSS selectors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-selectors, selectors-api

How could I test CSS1-3 selectors to check that they get the correct elements, e.g. with JavaScript (maybe jQuery)?

Comment: May I suggest you read [this](http://lea.verou.me/2011/07/detecting-css-selectors-support-my-jsconf-eu-talk/) blog article, which discusses your exact problem and gives a few solutions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest traditional way by far is to not use JavaScript at all, and just set up a test page by hand where you can test selectors to your heart's content. The test cases you see on the Web (like the well-known [CSS3.info Selectors Test](http://www.css3.info/selectors-test)) are really just souped-up versions hosted online.

But if you're looking for a JavaScript method, you can try the [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api). It's available in modern DOM implementations (IE8+ and others) and it provides a JavaScript frontend for querying the DOM for element nodes using CSS selectors, as well as testing CSS selectors natively supported by a given browser.

*(For browsers that don't implement the Selectors API, you'll have to rely on jQuery, but remember that it provides support for a different set of selectors than what a browser supports as well as its own non-standard extensions which aren't found in the [Selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors). An example of using jQuery with Chrome's JavaScript console to test a selector can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007060/what-tool-can-i-use-to-test-the-contains-css3-pseudo-class-in-a-browser/9008184#9008184).)*

Call `querySelector()` or `querySelectorAll()` depending on what you want to test, and check the return value (preferably in your browser's developer tools since you're just testing):

- If matches are found, the former method returns the first `Element` matched while the latter returns all elements matched as a `NodeList`.
- If nothing is found, the former returns `null` while the latter returns an empty `NodeList`.
- If the selector is invalid, an exception will be thrown which you can catch.

Here are some examples with the command editor (multiline) in Firebug's console on Firefox 10, tested on [this very question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165859/how-do-i-test-css-selectors-in-javascript):

- Finding the first `h1` in `body`:

  ```js
  var h1 = document.body.querySelector('h1');
  console.log(h1);
  ```

  ```html
  <h1 itemprop="name">
  ```
- Querying descendants of that `h1` element we just found:

  ```js
  var subnodes = h1.querySelectorAll('*');
  console.log(subnodes[0]);
  ```

  ```html
  <a class="question-hyperlink" href="/questions/9165859/how-do-i-test-css-selectors-in-javascript">
  ```
- Testing the `:-moz-any()` pseudo-class in Firefox (`:-webkit-any()` in Safari/Chrome):

  ```js
  // This selector works identically to h1 > a, li > a
  var hyperlinks = document.querySelectorAll(':-moz-any(h1, li) > a');
  console.log(hyperlinks);
  ```

  ```
  [a#nav-questions /questions, a#nav-tags /tags, a#nav-users /users, a#nav-badges /badges, a#nav-unanswered /unanswered, a#nav-askquestion /questions/ask, a.question-hyperlink /questio...vascript]
  ```
- Testing a nonexistent selector (that [perhaps many of us wish did exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107)):

  ```js
  // :first-of-class doesn't exist!
  var selector = 'div.answer:first-of-class';

  try {
      var firstAnswer = document.querySelector(selector);
      console.log(firstAnswer);
  } catch (e) {
      console.log('Invalid selector: ' + selector);
  }
  ```

  ```
  Invalid selector: div.answer:first-of-class
  ```

Answer (score 2):

http://selectorgadget.com is quite nice to test and build CSS selectors. Just drag and drop a piece of JavaScript they provide into your bookmarks bar and click it whenever you need.