# How to detect whether browser supports :invalid pseudoclass?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, pseudo-class, browser-feature-detection

I tried to use Modernizr, but it seems not to support this feature detection. 
I also read that it is difficult or even inmpossible to access pseudoclasses from javascript, because they are not part of DOM. So, after surfing the web I found no relevant information.
I need an easy solution without the need to download heavy libraries.
Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094865/test-if-a-browser-supports-a-css-selector

Answer (score 0):

Trap an error from `querySelector` or `matches`, which parses the selector and throws an error if it is not valid:

```
function invalid_pseudoclass_support () {
    var support = true;
    try {
        document.querySelector(':invalid');
    } catch (e) {
        support = false;
    }
    return support;
}
```