# How to check if browser supports CSS general sibling selector ~

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, cross-browser

How can I test with Javascript (jQuery) if the browser supports the css general sibling selector `~`?

Example:

```
#toggled:checked ~ #sidebar {
    display: block;
}
```

That CSS code won't work in IE 8-, Firefox 3-, Safari 3.1-, so in those cases I need to apply a Javascript alternative to display the `#sidebar` block.

Comment: Use JavaScript and see if it is visible?

Comment: More general, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094865/test-if-a-browser-supports-a-css-selector perhaps, though if you're going that far back you might have to polyfill `querySelector` too for the method in that answer, and I'm not sure if `Element.matches` (Javascript) will always match up with the browser's CSS selector implementation

Comment: The general sibling selector states it supports IE7, safari 3 and firefox 1. So I think that in this case, it's the :checked selector that doesn't work in IE8, since it's supposed to be IE9+ . SO maybe you can change it into `#toggled.checked ~ #sidebar` and then use JS to add/remove the `.checked` class from the  toggled element upon click. That should be IE8 compatible on first sight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@epascarello is right in comments, why not using JS?

For instance, in JS (untested - using jQuery):

```
let isRuleApplied = (selector, keyApplied, valueApplied) => {
  let element = $(selector);
  return element && element.css(keyApplied) === valueApplied;
};

console.log(isRuleApplied('#toggled:checked ~ #sidebar', 'display', 'block'));
```

Or just use `style` property of `getElementById` node, or `querySelector` using Vanilla JS.

Kudos to the idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094865/test-if-a-browser-supports-a-css-selector).

Comment: The idea in the original post works great, thanks for the solution!