# How to style parent when parent contains specific child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some html that looks like this:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

I want to apply a default background color to `#parent` except for when it contains a `#child`.

So the CSS should end up looking something like this:

```
#parent {
  background: red
}
#parent:contains(#child) {
  background: none
}
```

However, I can't get the `:contains` pseudo selector to work that way. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`:contains()` was only intended to match elements containing certain text](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors), not elements containing certain other elements. It is because of the complications associated with matching elements by text that there were almost no browser implementations, leading to [`:contains()` being dropped from the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#content-selectors).

Since [there is no parent selector in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), and `:has()` (which does look at elements) only exists in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector), you won't be able to achieve this with CSS [yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector/1014958#1014958).

For the record, [jQuery implements `:contains()` as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007060/what-tool-can-i-use-to-test-the-contains-css3-pseudo-class-in-a-browser/9008184#9008184), but it does so according to the old spec, so it uses the name `:has()` for elements instead.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery

```
if($("#child").length>0) $("#parent").css("backgroundColor","#fff");
```

Its not possible with pure css.

Comment: with jQuery you can do $('#parent:has(#child)').css...but I am going for a CSS only solution.