# Attach an image to any word

Tags: css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I'd like to attach images to specific words but cannot find the right CSS selector to do so.

I have a portion of my site which displays data as it's pulled from a database, so adding classes or id's to certain words is not an option for me. **I need the css to simply display a background image wherever that word (or in this case, name) is found on the page.**

For example, in the following (which is pulled from a database):

```
<td class="data1"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1">Patrick</font></td>
```

I would like to add a background image where the name `Patrick` is found.

I tried variations of,

```
td[.table1 *='Parick'] { 
    background-image:url(../images/accept.png);
```

but that didn't get me anywhere. And since it's not in a `<span>` or `<div>` or even a link, I can't figure it out. If you have any ideas or a jQuery workaround, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I thought that might be true. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can guarantee the names only appear as the only text nodes in elements, you can use a simple jQuery selector...

```
$(':contains("Patrick")').addClass('name');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rHuec/).

If there may be surrounding whitespace and/or the search should be case insensitive, try...

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase() == 'patrick';
}).addClass('name');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PjTWr/).

If you need to find the name anywhere in any text node and then you need to wrap it with an element, try...

```
$('*').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).each(function() {
    var node = this;
    this.data.replace(/\bPatrick\b/i, function(all, offset) {
        var chunk = node.splitText(offset);
        chunk.data = chunk.data.substr(all.length);
        var span = $('<span />', {
            'class': 'name',
            text: all
        });
        $(node).after(span);
    });
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXXbn/).

I would recommend using the third example.

Comment: Hmmm. `$(':contains("Patrick")').addClass('name');` worked, but it added the image to the entire page because the name was found. I need to make it specific to the word itself, so the css will add the image to the left of that word each time it's found. I tried, `$('td:contains("Patrick")').addClass('name');` and that only put it outside the entire table. My corresponding CSS is: `.name { 
 background-image:url(../images/accept.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:left;`

Comment: @Toasterdroid Try the last example, it works perfect in my fiddle :)

Comment: Oh cool. Well, I must be putting the script in the wrong place. I'll tinker around with it until I get it to work as your jsFiddle example does. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `:contains()` used to exist in CSS but was dropped for, bah, I'll just point you to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781141/why-h3nth-child1containsa-selector-doesnt-work/4781167#4781167 One of the main reasons it was dropped is because of disasters like the one described by @Toasterdroid: if you use the pseudo-class alone without any other selectors it will add the class to that `<font>` element **and every single one of its ancestors**, all the way back up to the `<html>` element!

Comment: If that `<font>` tag is going to be there, you may as well just use `font:contains("Patrick")` and hunt for the right element to add the class to (if not that tag).