# Selecting an element in the same row as specific text

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I'm using Selenium IDE 1.7.1 to select the checkbox that corresponds with invoice # 405357.  Css seems to allow me to move forward in selecting an element, but not backward.
So this would select the $420:

```
css=td:contains('405357') + td
```

Any ideas for a workaround in order to select a the checkbox? Ideally the workaround wouldn't involve going backward or forward but would just say select checkbox

```
css=input#paymentsForm_invoiceToPayIds if td:contains('405357')
```

I'd prefer it to be in CSS, but XPath would be ok too.

Thank you!

[image]

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input id="paymentsForm_invoiceToPayIds" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateInvoices(this)" value="405357" name="invoiceToPayIds">
<input id="__checkbox_paymentsForm_invoiceToPayIds" type="hidden" value="405357" name="__checkbox_invoiceToPayIds">
</td>
<td>405357</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Be careful - while you can have multiple checkboxes of the same name in order to group them, they must each have their own unique ID. Just sticking the invoice ID at the end of each checkbox ID should do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `:contains()` works for the parent `tr` too. Try this:

```
css=tr:contains('405357') input[type="checkbox"]
```

Comment: Sweeet - precisely what I was looking for. This will work even if the invoice id# isn't in the checkbox attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in real CSS, because real CSS doesn't have `:contains`.  But in XPath, it's simple: `//tr[//input[@value="405357"]]//input[@type="checkbox"]`, which means "The checkbox contained in the table row that contains an input field with the value '405357'".

Comment: Actually, [CSS *used* to have `:contains()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781141/why-h3nth-child1containsa-selector-doesnt-work/4781167#4781167), then it got dropped, but Selenium implements it anyway.

Comment: `:contains()`  was only a proposal, and it got dropped between 7 and 11 years ago, long before [CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929) was published.  People need to get over that, it ain't never comin' back :-)

Comment: Selenium doesn't implement `:contains()`.  But depending on the browser you're using, the browser may, or Selenium may fall back to using [Sizzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizzle_(selector_engine)), which does.  So it's an iffy proposition, and should be avoided.

Comment: Huh, I was under the impression that Selenium used its own selector engine all along :/

Answer (score 0):

```
//input[@type='checkbox' and @value="405357"]
```

try out this one

Comment: No dice - the checkbox is the first input element, and the one with the value is the second.

Comment: Hey Ross, just fyi, but Rohit's code also works and properly selects the checkbox.

Comment: ohhkk..no worries, you got your solution..vote doesn't matters a lot..:)