# Why is `content:""` negating selectors below it?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, css-content

I am having a very odd problem.

So I have a huge pile of CSS, and among many selectors within it, I have selector that looks like this, which is working just fine:

```css
.spoilertop, #QUOTETOP, #CODETOP, .utubetop {
    padding-left: 44px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

But then I add a selector that looks like this just above it:

```css
.spoilermain:after, #QUOTE:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -24px;
    left: 12px;
    border-width: 24px 24px 0 0;
    border-color: transparent #766161;
    border-style: solid;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
}​
```

And then the `spoilertop, #QUOTETOP, #CODETOP, .utubetop  { }` stops working. It doesn't give me the visual effect that it should've given.

I tested it again with different selector. I have a selector that looks like this:

```css
#recaptcha {
    background:#766161!important;
    font-size:11px;
}
```

Then I add this above it:

```css
.utubemain:after, #CODE:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -24px;
    left: 12px;
    border-width: 24px 24px 0 0;
    border-color: transparent #c08f84;
    border-style: solid;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
}​
```

Again, the `#recaptcha { }` stops working.

I have tried to remove the properties one by one, and I found that the `content: "";` is the one which is causing problem. For now the solution is putting a random unused selector below the `{ content: ""; }`. So for example it will look like this:

```css
.spoilermain:after, #QUOTE:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -24px;
    left: 12px;
    border-width: 24px 24px 0 0;
    border-color: transparent #766161;
    border-style: solid;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
}​

.some-line {
    border:#000;
    background:#200;
}

.spoilertop, #QUOTETOP, #CODETOP, .utubetop {
    padding-left: 44px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

But that solution is kind of troublesome if I have a lot `content: "";`. And I'm really confused why is that kind of problem happening.

So... could anyone help me explain why?

Comment: What is the point of `content:"";`? Are you actually using an empty string in your code?

Comment: That is not supposed to happen. Can you provide an example page?

Comment: @bhamlin: I need that to create speech bubble

Comment: @Pumba80 Yes, it is really weird. About the example, since I was working in localhost and solved that problem (with that solution), I'll try to recreate it again. Oddly this does not occur if I start a new file though.

Comment: @Tim Medora: `content` is not a pseudo-class.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - you are correct, it's a property not a pseudo-class (bad edit on my part). There is a `:contains` pseudo-class which *pertains* to content, but it has nothing to do with this question. http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors

Comment: @Tim Medora: There used to be one, but [not anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781141/why-h3nth-child1containsa-selector-doesnt-work/4781167#4781167) ;)

Comment: _I would not think this would make a difference_, but have you tried using single quotes `content: '';` instead of double quotes? That's what I normally use when doing that, and I have never experienced the issue you mention. It really should not matter, but maybe it does.

Comment: @ScottS: yup, I have tried that. No difference, unfortunately. :/

Answer (score 0):

This breaks the rule on redundancy, however, have you tried separate declarations for .spoilermain:after and #QUOTE:after?

Comment: The empty string creates an [anonymous box](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#pending-inheritance) combined with display:block overrides the width:0 declaration, creating an invisible layer that overlaps other elements. Use display:inline instead, or try using "\A" as the value and add a border around the element so you can verify its dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

before and after are pseudo-elements but not pseudo-classes. So they shall be used as this:

```
.spoilermain::after 
{
}
```

but NOT as you did

```
.spoilermain:after 
{
}
```

Some browsers are quite permissive on that but in strict mode that should cause an error.