# Can I accomplish this with CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I've got elements like this:

```
<a href="something">A</a>
<a href="something_else">B</a>
<a href="something">A</a>
<a href="...">C</a>
```

I know I can use something like

```
body
{
    counter-reset:section;
}

a:before
{
    counter-increment:section;
    content:counter(section)". ";
}
```

to get

```
1. A
2. B
3. A
4. C
```

but is there a way to get the following?

```
1. A
2. B
1. A
3. C
```

ie. uniquely identify all links on a page by prefixing the text with the same number.

Note: hardcoding specific URLs isn't an option, I'm potentially dealing with hundreds of links and don't know the URLs ahead of time.

I realize this would be easy/possible with javascript, I am only interested in CSS-based solutions or an explanation of why this isn't possible with CSS.

Comment: it works for me. What browser did you try it on?

(you can see my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/CVW7Y/)

Comment: @ramsesoriginal: That's what the question said, but it is not the intended result. Read the question again.

Comment: How do you identify those links? Do you identify them by their text or their `href`?

Comment: Ideally by the URLs but it shouldn't matter either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got what you mean with your question. Just with plain CSS it's not possible (at least not cross-platform..)

If you can use javascript, you have several possibilities.

My preference would be to use a data-attribute to hold the value, for this example I chose `data-counter`. If you do like this, the CSS becomes trivial:

**CSS**

```
a:before
{
   content:attr(data-counter)". ";
}​
```

And the Javascript would look like this if you have jQuery:

**JS with jQuery**

```
var linkcounter = {};
var counter = 0;
$("a").each(function() {
    if (!linkcounter.hasOwnProperty($(this).attr("href"))) {
        counter++;
        linkcounter[$(this).attr("href")] = counter;
    }
    $(this).attr("data-counter", linkcounter[$(this).attr("href")]);
});
```

​
or like this without jQuery:

**vanilla JS**

```
var linkcounter = {};
var counter = 0;
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    if (!linkcounter.hasOwnProperty(anchors[i].getAttribute("href"))) {
        counter++;
        linkcounter[anchors[i].getAttribute("href")] = counter;
    }
    anchors[i].setAttribute("data-counter", linkcounter[anchors[i].getAttribute("href")]);
}
```

You can view the version without jQUery here: http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/CVW7Y/5

And the version with jQuery here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/CVW7Y/4

Sadly there is no CSS only way to do this (yet). I hope this helps.
​

Comment: Thanks!  As an aside, is there a way to hide duplicate links using CSS?  If my results were 1. A, 2. B, 3. C that would be better than nothing (can't use JS.)

Comment: @Emory: You won't be able to unless the links are all contained in the same parent and you know the URLs beforehand.

Comment: Ok, well, I guess there's nothing left to do but mark this as solved and move on. Thanks @BoltClock!

Comment: @BoltClock nailed it: if they are in the same parent, and you know the links beforehand, you can work with `:first-child` and similar. You can also use `HTML Components` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531018.aspx) you you are in a Internet-Explorer only environment.. but I would strongly recommend to stay away from such ugly solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get this behaviour with pure CSS, and you need Javascript. And there are always cases like this:

```
http://google.com/
http://google.com
google.com
google.com/
www.google.com
```

You get the point.

---

In jQuery this is quite trivial, so I'd suggest you use that.

Comment: the bottom 3 will be interpreted as relative links, because they do not have the `http://` prefix

Comment: I'm not concerned with those cases at present, thanks though!

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs: but it is still an issue, because they __look__ like links :)

Comment: Trying to style a subreddit so javascript isn't an option - most things are simple with jQuery... XD

Comment: I'm sorry, what's a subreddit?

Comment: No problem - a subreddit is a sub-forum on reddit.com, which can use a custom stylesheet.

Comment: Emory: Google "Greasemonkey".

Comment: nightcracker: I thought about it earlier but I wasn't aware they'd released on Chrome, I might just go this route! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use :contains but I'm not sure how supported it is so you might be better off with JavaScript.

```js
a:contains("A") {
    /* Styles here */
}

a:contains("B") {
    /* Styles here */
}
```

**EDIT:**

Apparently :contains isn't supported at all. I'll leave this up here though so no one else bothers putting it.

You could use :contains in jQuery though and add a class accordingly.

```js
$('a:contains(A)').addClass('CLASS_NAME');
```

Comment: `:contains()` is not supported at all (except some builds of KHTML which I don't think are in use anymore).

Comment: I appreciate the help, and I know jQuery is good tech, but I'm asking about CSS here =/

Comment: Not a problem. I'm not sure it's possible so just providing an alternative if needed.

Comment: Cool, I just wanted people suggesting perfectly valid javascript-based solutions to understand why I'm not accepting answers yet! XD

Comment: @BoltClock, they even left an explicit *blank* entry where the `:contains` spec used to be, down at the W3C recommendations (also assigned with an eerie number, 'sup with that?) **: )**

Comment: @Eliran M. - Why did you edit this answer? From what I can see, all you've done is remove all lines of code and put them back!

Comment: @techfoobar - just added google-highlighter code comments (see the edit description) - i have a nasty habit of highlighting code even when it's a one-liner :)

Comment: @Eliran M.: Yes, you can still find a definition [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors) - in the same section number, [oddly enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781141/why-doesnt-the-selector-h3nth-child1containsa-work/4781167#comment-5294495).

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery is OK, this can be done by manipulating the `:before` pseudo element's content:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rwMWx/2/

**JS**

```js
var labels = [
    "1",
    "2",
    "1",
    "3"
    // and so on...    
];

// OR maybe put in some algo for this sequence

$('a').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('data-label', labels[i] + '. ');
});
```

**CSS**

```css
a:before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    color: red;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: @Eliran M. - Why did you edit this answer? From what I can see, all you've done is remove all lines of code and put them back!

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
var counter = 0, cache = {};
$('a').each(function (i, a) {
    a = $(a);
    var href = a.attr('href');
    var c = cache[href];
    if (!c) {
        counter++;
        c = counter;
        cache[href] = c;
    }
    a.text(c + '. ' + a.text());
});
​
```

I'm using jQuery, and that's how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/pDLbQ/

Comment: I appreciate the attempt but that's not CSS.  I, too, love jQuery.

Comment: I'm almost sure that it's impossible to solve the problem just using CSS.