# How to select a span with a text inside a div using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The structure is like this(taken from browser), it is dynamically generated in share point Mysite. I do not have control over HTML. I need to hide the whole tr using css. The catch is that there are numerous similar tr structure in the page but with different text in span.Please suggest a way to hide only the tr with text **Social Notification Properties**

```
<tr class = "ms-WPHeader">
<td colspan ="3">
<div class = "ms-WPTitle">
<span>
Text -Social Notification Properties
```

I have tried this so far but failed.

```
td[class ~="ms-WPHeader"]+tr+td+div+span[Text ~="Newsfeed"]
{
 display:none;
 }
```

and this

```
.ms-WPHeader ~ .ms-WPTitle.span[Text ~="Newsfeed"]
{
display:none;
}
```

using this hides all the span which is obvious

```
.ms-WPTitle span
{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to use lower-level elements to restrict a selector, only higher ones. You could use JavaScript with XPath to select your tr, then attach a style attribute directly to it; it can't be done in CSS.

Comment: hi @Dee i want share that if don't have your control over **making** HTML but you can add a class to the identical Tables you want to work with and just give that class the css Property then may b you achieve your goal easily

Comment: which kind of access you are talking about.?

Comment: see what i have given sample try what i want to say with the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to neglect the inability of CSS to select text node.

Below there are two tables in which the second table text is visible.

```js
$(".ms-WPHeader:contains('Text-Social Notification Properties')").css("display", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="ms-WPHeader">
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="ms-WPTitle">
        <span>Text-Social Notification Properties</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr class="ms-WPHeader">
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="ms-WPTitle">
        <span>I am visible though</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't select elements with a specific text inside via CSS. What you can do though is to via jQuery look for that element and then add a class to it, so that you then can select it via CSS.

```
$("span:contains('Social Notification Properties')").addClass('hide');
```

And then in CSS

```
.hide{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: it is hiding the whole page

Answer (score 2):

this is what i still suggest that you can use like this

```js
$('table').addClass("hide_this_tr");
```

```css
.hide_this_tr tr{
    display : none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="WPHeader">
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="WPTitle">
        <span>Text-Social Notification Properties</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr class="WPHeader">
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="WPTitle">
        <span>I am visible though</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As what i understand about what you want to achieve this is what my try is.

Answer (score 1):

There's a specification for `:contains('')` pseudo-class, but I'm not able to make it work on any browser.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors

But jQuery make this selector work as Gustaf said :

```
$("span:contains('Social Notification Properties')");
```

It's the only way to achieve this at the moment.

Comment: :contains() was removed from the spec a decade ago - you can see this by going to the latest version of the spec, which you can find a link to at the very top of the page. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781141/why-doesnt-the-selector-h3nth-child1containsa-work/4781167#4781167

Answer (score 1):

Without using jQuery, plain JavaScript using XPath (as mentioned in comments):

```js
var snapshot = document.evaluate(
  "//tr[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' ms-WPHeader ')][contains(.//span, 'saurus')]",
  document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null
);
for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.snapshotLength; i++) {
  snapshot.snapshotItem(i).classList.add("highlight");
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr class = "ms-WPHeader">
      <td colspan ="3">
        <div class = "ms-WPTitle">
          <span>
            Irrelevant text
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "ms-WPHeader">
      <td colspan ="3">
        <div class = "ms-WPTitle">
          <span>
            A wild stegosaurus appears!
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "ms-WPHeader">
      <td colspan ="3">
        <div class = "ms-WPTitle">
          <span>
            More irrelevant text
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "wrongClass">
      <td colspan ="3">
        <div class = "wrongClassTitle">
          <span>
            Brontosaurus in a wrong TR
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The XPath for "having a class", simple in CSS, is a bit of a pain in XPath; but it can be simplified quite a bit if you know the exact class attribute (i.e. "there will be no other classes but `ms-WPHeader` there"):

```
"//tr[@class='ms-WPHeader'][contains(.//span, 'saurus')]"
```

Comment: thanks, but I solved it with jquery. Will book mark this for future use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:nth-child()` if the structure of your page **doesn't change** :

To hide the 1st `tr` with the class `ms-WPHeader` (Be carreful: this will hide every 1st `tr` in each `table`):

```
table tr.ms-WPHeader:nth-child(1) {//hide the 1st tr in table
    display: none;
}
```

JSFidlle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/no891emk/

Comment: sadly the contents changes according to user preference.

Comment: @Dee So you need to use JS or/and JQuery to perform that. a pure CSS solution doesn't exists (yet)

Answer (score 0):

span is a webelement so you can select this using CSS Selector.
and then you can do WebElement.getText() to retrieve the text. No need to use xpath for this.