# Is there a native CSS replacement for :has-text()?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I see that MDN Web Docs now lists the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class among others, but is there something similar to [`:has-text()`](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Procedural-cosmetic-filters#subjecthas-textneedle) from uBlock Origin?

```
span:has-text(Promoted by) {
  display: none;
}
```

uBlock Origin has both, so I'm wondering whether I have simply overlooked something on MDN.

Comment: As the article says, _"Procedural means JavaScript code will find DOM elements that it must hide. A procedural cosmetic filter uses a filter operator that will tell uBO how to find/filter DOM elements to find which DOM elements to target."_ So it's not in native CSS yet.

Comment: Safari is the only thing that supports `:has()` but what is it you're really trying to accomplish? Are you looking for a css selector that will search an elements content for a specific string? Because that's not a thing and shouldn't be in what CSS is for anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm wrong, this is not possible in CSS.

The "easiest alternative way" is to use XPath, but it's not usable in CSS:

```
//a[contains(text(),"Promoted by")]
//a[text()="Promoted by"] (exact match)
```

Comment: FWIW, it seems [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) is not deprecated, but it is jQuery selector, not CSS.

Comment: @johnc.j. Good point, my memory is playing tricks on me ! I've edited my post to avoid confusion.

Comment: @john c. j.: No, NetSkylz was right, it was deprecated and then removed from the spec; its existence in jQuery is non-standard. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781141/why-doesnt-the-selector-h3nth-child1containsa-work/4781167#4781167