# CSS selector to retrieve based on text value

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

```
<Span class='abc' id='cell-123'>test123</span>
```

How can I retrieve the value of span based on value

```
Xpath = //span[text()='test123']
CSS = span:contains('test123')
```

Above CSS is not working is the syntax correct? Can anyone help with how to retrieve the element value by CSS selector

Comment: Can you clarify more ? Do you want to retrieve `test123` from given `HTML` ? And what error are you getting ?

Comment: I want to get the element based on text since that entry in span was created in the above step. Hence I want to find the element by tag span and text present test123 using css selector

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't the selector h3:nth-child(1):contains('a') work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781141/why-doesnt-the-selector-h3nth-child1containsa-work)

Comment: `contains` is no longer available so you have to use xpath